# How to include libraries in Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have dynamic web project with Struts2 and Hibernate. I need to send this project to another computer for examination. I have libraries with external dependencies. 
To solve it, I converted my project to Maven project and added Struts2 and Hibernate dependencies in pom.xml, but I still have `Apache Tomcat v8.0` and `JRE System Library` libraries which refer on external directories. 
How should I include these libraries?

Comment: What are the Tomcat and JRE dependencies?  When you build the project with maven do you get errors?  If so can you post them please?

Answer (score 1):

The JRE is included automatically. Add this properties to pom.xml to control the java version (you need [at least Java 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)):

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
<properties>
```

Tomcat 8 is a servlet container, so you need to include the servlet api, as a "provided" dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

That means, the library will be available while in development and not be available in production, because it is already included in your servers classpath.